# wordpress (NovelLite theme) slider image is offset (ie. certain images start at a lower height than the rest)

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

[how the website looks like when you first enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zU19V.jpg)

[how the website looks like when you adjust your screen size while the slider is showing this particular image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63xsl.png)

I'm not sure whether my description will suffice, but here it goes.

The first link shows that when you first enter the website, the first slider-image will be offset (ie. placed lower than the rest and thus, is cut off at the bottom; the other images are alright).

Next, when the screen/browser is resized (either bigger or smaller), the particular image shown on the slider at that point in time will be the one that is offset (while the rest are alright, ie. the first slider-image is now in the correct position).

All the slider-images are of the same dimension, and they are in `<ul>`, with each image in an individual `<li>`.

Right now, a portion of the CSS codes go like this:

```
ul.slides-container {
min-width: 1080px;
max-height: 500px;
```

}

```
ul.slides-container li img {
position: absolute;
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
```

}

I've tried setting `position: initial !important;` instead, which will resolve the issue of the misalignment, but it makes the images "unresponsive" (like when I reduce the size of the screen, the image gets cut off). Also, the right side of the images tend to be cut off as well, unless I:

- reduce the screen size (but keeping the width at the maximum length my laptop screen allows); OR
- remove `max-height`, in which case the width will be at its appropriate maximum, but the bottom part of the image will be cut off.

I've tried variations of `width: auto;` etc etc other seeemingly related solutions I've managed to Google, but none of them worked. It could perhaps be a JavaScript issue (which seems to be the solution for some people) but those solutions didn't seem closely related to mine and besides, I'm not too familiar with JS.

So I guess, the summarised question/main point would be: **how do I get the images to fit into the slider?**

P.S. I'm unable to provide the link to the website as it is not my right to do so. Really sorry about that.

Comment: Hi, are all the images the exact same size?

Comment: Yeap, they are of the same dimension

Comment: Do you have a url? Hard to diagnose from a screenshot.

Comment: Right now, the site is using another theme for 'live' preview. Hence, I didn't provide the url. Sorry about that. Will it help if I provide more of the relevant WordPress codes instead?

Comment: Documentation here but not much on the slider: http://www.themehunk.com/novellite-theme-documentation/. I recommend first removing the styling css and making sure all images are the same size and see what happens. If there's text, make sure there's the same amount of text per slide too. Without seeing the code I'm flying blind here a little bit. :)

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/style | http://www.filedropper.com/home-slider |
 http://www.filedropper.com/jquerysuperslides | http://www.filedropper.com/jqueryflexslider | http://www.filedropper.com/jquerybxslider | Will these help? I've only edited the first 2  ( CSS and php for the slider), but not the js files because i'm unfamiliar with that...